# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to \pi} \frac{\sqrt{1-\tan x}-\sqrt{1+\tan x}}{\sin2x}$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

I tried several times to solve the problem by changing the value, but I still could not solve it.

$$\lim_{x\to \pi} \frac{\sqrt{1-\tan x}-\sqrt{1+\tan x}}{\sin2x}$$

I have tried simplifying the values by replacing the tangent with $\sin x/\cos x$, or opening $\sin2x$ with the derivative $2\sin(x)\cos(x)$

The answer is $1/2$. I did not copy from photoMath, because it showed a very strange way of solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to \pi} \frac{\sqrt{1-\tan x}-\sqrt{1+\tan x}}{\sin2x}=\lim_{x\to \pi}\frac{-2\tan x}{\sin 2x(\sqrt{1-\tan x}+\sqrt{1+\tan x})}\\=\lim_{x\to \pi}\frac{-2 \tan x}{\sin 2x}\lim_{x\to \pi}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\tan x}+\sqrt{1+\tan x}}, $$

and

$$\lim_{x\to \pi}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\tan x}+\sqrt{1+\tan x}}=\frac12$$ and $$\lim_{x\to \pi}\frac{-2 \tan x}{\sin 2x}=-1$$

Comment: Thank you very much. You helped me.

Comment: I wanted to ask you. How did you get -2tanx?

Comment: $(\sqrt{1-\tan x}+\sqrt{1+\tan x})(\sqrt{1-\tan x}-\sqrt{1+\tan x})=-2\tan x$

Answer (score 0):

L'Hospital's rule can also solve this problem.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWlLA.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.